# How can I throttle bandwidth for iTunes only?

Tags: itunes, applications, data-transfer, internet

I saw a few questions asked and suggest Waterproof and a few other apps, but it seems to throttle everything outgoing on my Mac. I want to only throttle the download speed on iTunes. I normally use jDownloader to download things, and I am able to put a speed cap on my downloads, is there a way to do that for iTunes?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Throttled](http://intrarts.com/throttledcli.html) which should let you set a global or application specific speed limit

Comment: Does not support yosemite and later :(